# when im adding the Report Wizard in the folder it popups the error

Tags: asp.net

This is the PopUp Error

> Could not load type i TextSharp.color from assembly
>   itextsharp.version=5.5.3.0. Culture= netural.PublicKey
>   Token=8354ae6d2174ddca

[image]
Kindly help me

Comment: Did you at least check the assembly is referenced by your project?

Comment: Which one assembly...can u name..?

Comment: The one from the error message: itextsharp

Comment: what is with that report wizard...